# DecimalFormat and Math.pow

Tags: java, android

My program crashes and closes to a specific page that comes along.
In LogCat , lines 19, 82 seem to have a problem
what's the solution?!

```
public double format ( double value) {
    if ( value != 0){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
        return valueOf(df.format(value));
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

and

```
  public double getBMIKg(double height, double weight) {
    double meters = height/100;
    return format( weight / Math.pow(meters,2));
}
```

[error message in logCat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhBFu.jpg)

Comment: Add the stacktrace

Comment: maybe `meters` is 0? Why don't you paste the error message so we don't guess? :)

Comment: *FYI:* For performance, I believe `(meters * meters)` is faster than `Math.pow(meters,2)`.

Comment: inside the actual phone
 return-1;
Actually      ( value != 0){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
        return valueOf(df.format(value));

Does not work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public double getBMIKg(double height, double weight) {
    double meters = height/100.0;
    double res=meters!=0?weight / Math.pow(meters,2):0
    return format(res);
}
```

Comment: Did not change
The inside of the Android simulator works well, but does not work inside the actual phone

Comment: inside the actual phone return-1; Actually ( value != 0){ DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#"); return valueOf(df.format(value)); Does not work